# Problems with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trouble with selecting element attributes with jquery here is my HTML:

```
<a class="myselector" rel="I need this value"></a>

<div class="someClass" id="someID">
...bunch of elements/content
<input type="button" name="myInput" id="inputID" title="myInput Title" />
...bunch of elements/content
</div>
```

...bunch of elements/content

Here I'm trying to get the rel value of myselector here is how I tried but its not working :

```
$('#inputID').live('click',function(){
console.log($(this).closest('a.myselector').attr('rel'));
});
```

Also tried this since all is wrapped in wrapper div :

```
$('#inputID').live('click',function(){
console.log($(this).parent('div.wrapper').find('a.myselector').attr('rel'));
});
```

I get `undefined` value in firebug in both cases, I use live because `div#someID` is loaded in the document its not there when page first loads. Any advice, how can I get my selector rel value?

**EDIT:**

However when I look for `('a.myselector')` without rel attribute, I alert `Object object` and get console.log something `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
console.log($(this).closest('div.wrapper').find('a.myselector').attr('rel'));
```

Your first example in your question does not work because the anchor tag you are trying to select is [*not a parent/ancestor*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
console.log($(this).closest('a.myselector').attr('rel'));
```

Your second example would work if you changed `.parent()` to `.parents()`, as `.parent()` only traverses [*one level*](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) up the DOM, so the following:

```
console.log($(this).parents('div.wrapper').find('a.myselector').attr('rel'));
```

Comment: @Karim79 this seems fine to me, your second selector still outputs the undefined but still first one works, thank you I'll accept this answer when certain amount of time passes

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, have you tried accesing your rel value without using live (ie with direct id $("inputid").attr("rel") )?

I usually eliminate suspects one by one when faced with a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vkg8R/):

```
$('#inputID').live('click',function(){
  // alert($(this).parent().parent().html());
alert($(this).parent().parent().find('a.myselector').attr('rel'));
});
```

HTH

Comment: Tnx Raja but that is just not practical, its not a static website